# sum of deep nested form attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

rails 4 + cocoon

A little background:

`orders has_many order_products`
`order_products has_many product_sizes`

In an after_save call I would like to get the total quantity of all the products. I have a database column named `total_qty` in the `order_product` model. So in this pic the total would be 37.

[image: Screen shot]

order form

```
= f.simple_fields_for :order_products do |order_product|
    = render 'order_product_fields', :f => order_product
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Product', f, :order_products
```

order_product_fields

```
= f.simple_fields_for :product_sizes do |product_size|
      = render 'product_size_fields', :f => product_size
        = link_to_add_association 'Add Size', f, :product_sizes
```

product_size_fields

```
<div class="row nested-fields">
 = f.input :size_name, :collection => Order::SIZES, label: false, include_blank: false
 = f.input :qty, label: false, class: "<%= product_sizes.index %>"
 = link_to_remove_association f, class: 'btn btn-danger' do
  .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up digging deep and finding an answer in my brain.

product_size.rb

```
  def size_qty
    qty
  end
```

order_product.rb

```
  def total_size_qty
    product_sizes.map do |ps| ps.size_qty end
  end
```

order.rb

```
def total_order_product_qty
  order_products.map do |os| os.total_size_qty end
end
```